# Does my character's species/gender matter in Star Wars: Uprising?

Tags: star-wars-uprising

When you create a new character you have the option of 4 species and both male and female genders. Does this choice affect either your character's stats or the story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the choice is purely cosmetic according to this article: https://apptrigger.com/2015/09/14/star-wars-uprising-tips-tricks-and-strategies/